# Background in android layout is stretched

Tags: android, background, android-relativelayout

I put a background image to my Relative layout using `android:background="@drawable/rajat2"`, where rajat2 is an image in all the drawable folders.

It sets the background to my layout but the background comes stretched to the whole screen. 
I've tried putting the wallpaper through java code too but it still behaves the same!

Comment: what are you developing a wallpaper or application

Comment: an application ..but i was trying to add a background to the screen !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use draw9patch for the background image. it well help you.

Answer (score 4):

If your drawable size is not exactly the screen size, the background will be stretched to the entire screen size. Consider creating the drawable for each type of screen size so it doesn't appear stretched.

If you don't want the image to take up the entire screen size, consider using an `ImageView` instead, and placing that inside your layout.

Comment: What parameters does the image for uniform scaling?

Answer (score 0):

If You are developing an application then set the layout width and height as match parent 
and use 9 patch image for more exact value what you want